# Which paraphrase is correct?

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions, comparison, participles, paraphrasing

Being about the same size as a domestic chicken, the kiwi bird lays eggs that are very large in proportion to its body size.

A) The eggs of the kiwi bird are much larger than those of a domestic chicken although both birds are almost the same size.

B) The eggs of the kiwi are very large for its body, which is about as big as that of a domestic chicken.

Key says answer is A. I think "in proportion to its body" makes a comparison between eggs and the kiwi. But option A makes comparison between eggs of the kiwi and eggs of a chicken. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think answer B reproduces the exact information in the original sentence, as such I find it hard to criticise as a literal paraphrase.

Applying strict logic, the original sentence doesn't actually tell us specifically about the size of chicken eggs. The sentence implies that there is a usual relationship between size of bird and size of egg, and that the kiwi has an unusually high ratio. We might infer that the chicken has a more usual ratio, but that is not explicitly stated.

Hence I don't think that A is a literal paraphrase. However, I'd be pretty confident in inferring the truth of A from the original sentence, it's not likely that the author would mention chickens and fail to mention that their eggs too are unusually large, if that indeed were the case.

Comment: Thank you so much.